# Почему при старте системы не монтируется папка по samba?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, unix, mount

Приветствую.
Проблема в следующем.
При старте системы не монтируется сетевая папка на двух машинах из 10.
Монтируется только руками `mount -a`.
На остальных все в порядке.
Все по samba, версии клиентов одинаковые.
По какой причине это может быть?

Comment: Для начала - `cat /etc/fstab` (btw, откуда монтируется папка? если тоже с linux, то nfs+autofs вместо самбы имеет смысл)

Comment: Монтируется с linux, но есть машины с виндой, куда это должно монтироваться. Хочется понять почему на двух машинах(linux) это не работает

Comment: Sorry, удалённо-телепатическую читалку кнфигов и логов тут ещё не придумали...

Comment: Я понимаю, в течении мин. 30 закину конфиг.зам нет возможности

Comment: @PinkTux, к слову: *ms/windows* довольно давненько уже научили монтировать *nfs*. «через задний проход», конечно, но научили. @ KleinenberG, так что смысл использования *samba* довольно призрачен.

Comment: в fstab наверное написано noauto

Comment: //192.168.0.0/dir    /dir/dir      cifs    rw,_netdev,auto,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user="",pass=""    0 0

//192.168.0.0/dir2    /dir/dir/dir      cifs    rw,auto,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,user="",pass=""    0 0

Comment: вот fstab c самбой.
В превой строчке использовал _netdev, как посоветовали снизу.
Но факт в том что в логах видно что монитрование не происходит
По dmesq видно что интерфейс подинмается на дальше по cifs ни слова

Comment: А перенести конфиг с рабочей системы на нерабочую?

Comment: Решение проблемы крайне не понятно мне, в сетевых настройках я закоментировал строчку указвающую что gateway это сервер с которого разадется папка

Answer (score 1):

вероятно, среди опций монтирования отсутствует опция `_netdev`. цитата из [man-страницы](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=mount&category=8):

> **_netdev**
>   Файловая система, находящаяся на устройстве, которому требуется сетевой доступ (используется для предотвращения попыток системы монтировать эту файловую систему пока недоступна сеть).

её имеет смысл добавить и на тех компьютерах, где, по счастливому стечению обстоятельств, монтирование (пока) проходит успешно.

Comment: спасибо, но _netdev не решил проблему.
Решение проблемы крайне не понятно мне,
в сетевых настройках я закоментировал строчку указвающую что gateway это сервер с которого разадется папка.