# монтирование сетевой папки

Tags: linux, debian, mount

Уважаемые знатоки, столкнулся с такой проблемой. при указании сетевой папки в `/etc/fstab` и при перезагрузке сервера, данная папка не монтируется. Хотя если запустить команду `mount -a`, то папка будет смонтирована.

содержимое `/etc/fstab`

`//192.168.16.100/Delta /media/delta cifs user=user,password=1234,vers=1.0 0 0`

`mount -t cifs //192.168.16.100/Delta /media/delta -o user=user,password=1234,vers=1.0` - данная команда работает.

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы сетевая папка монтировалась при старте системы?

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.10 (wheezy)
Release:        7.10
Codename:       wheezy
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612463/178576

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Но по ссылке написано: *_netdev не решил проблему.* У меня та же самая проблема дома на "малинке". Я убрал монтирование сетевого диска из *fstab* и прописал команду *mount* в */etc/init.d/rc.local*. Не помогло. Перенёс в *.bashrc* пользователя. Не помогло. Но, если после загрузки системы монтировать руками - всё проходит нормально.

Comment: @Sergey я решил проблему таким образом. в `fstab` к монтирующей папке добавил опцию `_netdev`, после в папке `/etc/network/if-up.d` добавил скрипт с командой `mount -a -O _netdev`. Теперь у меня все работает

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев *я решил проблему* - увы, у меня не получается так... Ошибка монтирования -101.  Может быть Вы всё-таки вручную запускаете скрипт из папки */etc/network/if-up.d* ? Я просто не знаю, кто его запускает и когда...

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев Однако, если вручную выполнить команду *mount -a -O _netdev* то это тоже ничего не даёт...

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев И ещё, я не понял смысла выражения *к монтирующей папке добавил опцию*. Как это - опция у папки?!

Comment: @Sergey ну `user=user,password=1234,vers=1.0` это же сказать как опции(параметры)?